# I haven't been using virtual environments and i'm now learning about them. Should I delete python and reinstall it?

Tags: pip, dependencies, virtualenv, virtual-environment

Did I muddle up my system by installing packages in general without being in a specific virtual environment and need to start over?

Im not for sure if that is even the correct solution to delete it. I just want to make sure I don't have any dependencies floating around on my operating system I'm not aware of.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+remove+all+installed+packages